# Xcode source control not showing current branch changes

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I am running Xcode 8.2.1, and am using github version control. Normally, I am able to press Source Control in the top bar, and then Commit. This menu usually shows all of the files I have changed on the local branch, and I can click through the files and see the local diff. When I run "git status" in the terminal, the modified files show up. Are there any ways that this could be unlinked from my source control? I have set my Source Control preferences to Enabled, and have all of the options selected except "Show Git merge commits in history"

Answer (score 0):

No, you can’t unlink terminal from xcode.

In xcode, what you did is based on local working copies. And the git commands you used in terminal is also based on local git repo. So git status from xcode and terminal should always be synchronized.

If you want xcode to show which files are changed before you use source control -> commit to find the changed files, there is no good ways on xcode. You can use the command `git status` you find these files.

Or you can feedback this request [here](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/), such as change the icon to red check mark if the file is changed (no changed files with blue lock icon).

[image]

Comment: Ya, this was my understanding as well, but Xcode source control is never showing any changes, and terminal shows all my changes as they should be

Comment: So you want xcode to show which files are changed before you use source control -> commit to find the changed files? xcode can't do that now. I updated my answer.